# MongoDB conditional query depending on possible dates

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a scenario where I want to pull documents that have a `lastAlertSentDate` field that's over 30 days old. This will run in a daily cron job. Upon querying, this field will then be reset to NOW. So it's meant to act as a "rotating 30 day window" if you will.

The complication here is that the field won't exist if it hasn't been set yet. In this edge case, we'll then have to use a `createdDate` field of the document to do the 30-day comparison against.

So effectively, I want something like, "If `lastAlertSentDate` exists, then get all docs where it's older than 30days from now. ---Otherwise, get all docs where `createdDate` is older than 30days from now"

So the logic between both fields are the same, it's just the field itself that can be different. Because of this, I was thinking to first USE `addFields` a `dateToUseField` and then do a `match` on the second stage based on this.

```
  [
  {
    '$addFields': {
      'dateToUse': {
        '$cond': {
          'if': {
            '$ne': [
              '$lastAlertSentDate', undefined
            ]
          }, 
          'then': '$lastAlertSentDate', 
          'else': '$createdDate'
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$match': {
      'dateToUse': {
        '$lte': '30_DAYS_PRIOR'
      }
    }
  }
]
```

So the `else` part doesn't seem to work. It doesn't assign `$createdDate` to `dateToUse`.

What am I missing? Also, how can I condense this? I'm sure I don't need the `addFields` first and I can do everything within the `$match`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here:

1. Use a `$or` query with two predicates, where each of them is a `$and` predicate:

- Either `lastAlertSentDate` does not exists **and** `createdDate` > n
- Or `lastAlertSentDate` exists **and** it is > n

[Playground Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jq3aJdyjPxf)

```js
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      $and: [
        {
          "lastAlertSentDate": {
            "$exists": false
          }
        },
        {
          "createdDate": {
            $gt: 5
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      $and: [
        {
          "lastAlertSentDate": {
            "$exists": true
          }
        },
        {
          "lastAlertSentDate": {
            $gt: 5
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

2. Use an aggregation using the [$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/)

[Playground Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9J7FAOa73IE)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gt: [
          {
            "$ifNull": [
              "$lastAlertSentDate",
              "$createdDate"
            ]
          },
          5
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```